# Calling Grafana Angular TimePickerCtrl function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, grafana

I am creating my own date range picker for my embedded Grafana (v5.2.2) iframe in kiosk mode. However, I dunno how to call the [`TimePickerCtrl`](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/app/features/dashboard/timepicker/timepicker.ts) functions (e.g. `move(direction)` or `setRelativeFilter(timespan)`) outside the scope of Angular (e.g. from Chrome's console using javascript). I have tried using `angular.element($0).injector().scope()` (where `$0` is an element in grafana's time range widget), but it returns `undefined`.

P.S. I am an Angular novice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Grafana v5.2.2, I am able to get the `TimePickerCtrl` by using:

```
angular.element(grafanaJQuery("gf-time-picker")).controller("gfTimePicker").$scope.ctrl
```

Then I could use its member functions by:

```
ctrl.move(-1);
ctrl.setRelativeFilter({from: start, to: end});
```